# Bannerslider on clean css3 (no jQuery)

Tags: css, css-animations

I've made a bannerslider on clean CSS3 with no jQuery. It works in every Earth browser. How to make this work in IE-9?

http://jsfiddle.net/zBGNm/15/

I used @keyframes. Every <LI> is animated by an appropriate animation, that changes opacity and z-index of list items. Every <LI> has its own background, so it is seen, when list items cover each other during the animation. 
Here is CSS:

```
body {
background: url(http://htmler.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Subtle-Patterns-High-quality-patterns-for-your-next-web-project-1.png);
width: 50px;
height: 100%;}

#slider {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
position: fixed;
z-index:6;
}

#slider:hover li
{
-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

#slider li
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
position:absolute;
color: white;
}

#slider li:first-of-type
{
-webkit-animation: anim1 40s infinite;
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF6600, #550000);}

#slider li:nth-of-type(2)
{
-webkit-animation: anim2 40s infinite;
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FF0033, #330000);}


#slider li:nth-of-type(3)
{
-webkit-animation: anim3 40s infinite; 
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #9933CC, #330055);}


#slider li:nth-of-type(4)
{
-webkit-animation: anim4 40s infinite;
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #003366, #001133);}

#slider li:nth-of-type(5)
{
-webkit-animation: anim5 40s infinite;
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #99CC00, #115500);}

@-webkit-keyframes anim1 {
0% {z-index:6;opacity:0;}
5% {z-index:6; opacity:1;}
20% {z-index:6; opacity:1;}
21% {z-index:1;}
100% {z-index:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim2 {
0% {z-index:2;opacity:0;}
19% {z-index:2; opacity:0;}
20% {z-index:6; opacity:0;}
25% {z-index:6; opacity:1;}
40% {z-index:6; opacity:1;}
41% {z-index:2;}
100% {z-index:2;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim3 {
0% {z-index:3;opacity:0;}
39% {z-index:3; opacity:0;}
40% {z-index:6; opacity:0;}
45% {z-index:6; opacity:1;}
60% {z-index:6; opacity:1;}
61% {z-index:3;}
100% {z-index:3;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim4 {
0% {z-index:4;opacity:0;}
59% {z-index:4; opacity:0;}
60% {z-index:6; opacity:0;}
65% {z-index:6; opacity:1;}
80% {z-index:6; opacity:1;}
81% {z-index:4;}
100% {z-index:4;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim5 {
0% {z-index:5;opacity:1;}
5% {z-index:1;opacity:0;}
79% {z-index:5; opacity:0;}
80% {z-index:6; opacity:0;}
85% {z-index:6; opacity:1;}
100% {z-index:5;}
}
```

and the markup:

```
<html>
<body>
<ul id="slider">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are no prefixes for other browsers, it's in order to be short here. On my computer, I wrote all prefixes. As I have said, it works everywhere, but not in IE. Is there a workaround for this BRRRROOOOOOUUUUUUUZZZEEERRR??!!!!